# PSFTP: overwriting existing files

Tags: command-line, ssh, putty

I use psftp to sync directories on a linux box to my windows server (connection is initiated by the windows server). I use the "get -r /dir" command to get the files and directories recursively.

Is there any chance to get only the changed/new files so that existing files are not overwritten?

Thx,
Tobias

Comment: Belongs on superuser.com

Answer (score 2):

Using 'plain' ftp for syncing can be quite a hassle when the requirements grow. Once these kinds of questions are asked, you are probably better of using rsync, even if you are on windows. http://everythinglinux.org/rsync/

And on a side note: don't confuse keeping directories in sync with version control and the other way around (both often happen imho), I don't know what you're trying to sync but a git/svn/cvs repo might be better.

Comment: Thank you, I will try rsync. I need the sync mechanism just for having a local backup on my machine, so not SCM is needed.
Tobias